# Is it posible to integrate a remote Debugger in visual studio 2010 Express?

Tags: c#, debugging, add-in, remote-debugging, visual-studio-express

I can't use Visual Remote debugger in Visual 2010 Express, so i've tried to integrate this debugger :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jacdavis/archive/2008/02/20/new-debug-engine-sample.aspx

this project generate a .Addin File :

projectLauncher.dll and .pdb and ProjectLauncher.AddIn

With visual studio 2010 pro+, I can integrate it cause this version allow the Add-In Manager(tools>Add-In Manager) but i can't with Visual studio express 2010.

Is it possible to add a .Addin File without Add-In Manager in VS Express ?
Can i add a custom debugger in VS 2010 Express ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you need to pay for Visual Studio in order to use add ins